# Is there any way to get max value from a column in Pyspark other than collect()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to get the maximum value from a date type column in a pyspark dataframe. Currently, I am using a command like this:

```
df.select('col1').distinct().orderBy('col1').collect()[0]['col1']
```

Here `"col1"` is the datetime type column. It works fine but I want to avoid the use of `collect()` here as i am doubtful that my driver may get overflowed.

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to sort, you can just select the maximum:

```
res = df.select(max(col('col1')).alias('max_col1')).first().max_col1
```

Or you can use selectExpr

```
res = df1.selectExpr('max(diff) as max_col1').first().max_col1
```

Comment: okay.. one doubt..if i use first(), then it will not load the whole data into the driver right? which was my main issue?

Comment: @SamyakJain `first()` is called on the result of `max()`. That means the data frame on which `first()` is called can contain only one record.

Comment: For the first solution you suggested, `res = df.select(max(col('col1')).alias('max_col1')).first().max_col1`, I am getting `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable` in PySpark. So I don't think it works with PySpark..

Comment: @user1330974 exactly which call is raising that? Can you share your imports?

Comment: @ernest_k The imports are `import pyspark;from pyspark import SQLContext;from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window;from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, isnan, when, count` and this code `res = df.select(max(col('snapshot_day')).alias('max_snapshot_day')).first().max_snapshot_day` returns aforementioned tuple object is not callable error. Thank you!

Comment: @user1330974 Not obvious. I suspect you have a variable named `max` or called one of the other function names. One thing I don't see is `max` in your `pyspark.sql.functions` import list; although that doesn't immediately explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

much more shorter:
`maxValue = df.select(func.max(df.col)).collect()[0][0]`